# VB.net alternative for Selection

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel

In Excel VBA I could select some cells and then use the property `Selection` to refer to the selected cells.

What is the VB.net alternative to refer to a number of selected cells in an Excel worksheet?

I need to replace the code `Selection` in the below code with the appropriate code.

```
xlWorkSheet.ListObjects.Add(Excel.XlListObjectSourceType.xlSrcRange,_
Selection,, Excel.XlYesNoGuess.xlYes).Name = ("Table1")
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember that Selection is an Application object and can be reached throught it:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840834.aspx

But, be careful. Selection represents anything in Excel, a Range, a Picture. Through interop, it returns a dynamic object.

Try to play with Immediate Window in VBA, executing the code below, selecting different types of objects:

```
?TypeName(Application.Selection)
```

Happy coding!